# Teambuild not copying XAP fiesl to _PublishedWebsites

Tags: msbuild, silverlight-3.0, tfsbuild

I have a TFS build for sivelright and it copies all the files in the web project to _PublishedWebsites, except the xap file. Error is

> Web.csproj error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "Some.xap" to "c:\somewhere\Some.xap"  Could not find file "Some.xap".

What it is trying to do, from where it is trying to copy and why it is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your projects are built in the right order in your TFS Build Definition (Build Definition, Process, Required, Project to Build).